# No se como validar estas entradas dinámicas,

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, validación

"Tengo un problema de validacion de campos, y necesito saber cuantas entradas ha generado el usuario y validarlas al pulsar el siguiente boton, si son campos vacios o no contienen al menos dos campos llenos, no se puede pasar a la siguiente ventana , mi código se carga desde jquery al hacer clic en el botón +, lo que actualmente hace por mí es ir al siguiente paso sin validar la entrada.
en el css lo que hago es ocultar el contenedor del paso 3, primero hay que revisar que los campos del paso 1 esten validados y luego mostrar el paso 3 y ocultar el paso 1
"

```js
var i = 1;
$('#add').click(function() {
  // condicion que puede crear hasta un maximo de 4 campos 
  if (i >= 5) return
  i++;
  var crearTablas = $(
    '<tr id="row' + i + '">' +
    '<td>' +
    '<input type="text" name="name[] name" required placeholder="Nombre Jugador" pattern="^([A-Z]{1}[a-z]+\s?)*$" class="form-control name_list"  maxlength="100"/>' +
    '</td>' +
    '<td>' +
    '<button type="button" name="remove" id="' + i + '" class="btn btn-danger btn_remove">X</button>' +
    '</td>' +
    ' </tr>');
  $('#dynamic_field').append(crearTablas);
});
$(document).on('click', '.btn_remove', function() {
  // guardamos el identificador del boton en la variable
  var button_id = $(this).attr("id");
  
  $('#row' + button_id + '').remove();
  // luego ponemos el contador a 1 para resetear el contador
  i = 1;
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#next').click(function() {
    current_fs = $('#step-1');
    next_fs = $('#step-3');
    next_fs.show();
    current_fs.hide();
  });

  $('#previous').click(function() {
    current_fs = $('#step-3');
    next_fs = $('#step-1');
    next_fs.show();
    current_fs.hide();
  });
});
```

```css
#step-3{display:none;}
```

```html
<html lang="es">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<body>
  <!-- Button trigger modal -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#misModales">
    Reservar
  </button>
  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="misModales" data-bs-backdrop="static" data-bs-keyboard="false" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="abrirContenido" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <!-- aqui va el boton de cierre del modal -->
          <div class="btnCaja">
            <div class="btnCaja-fila panel-conf">
              <div class="btnCaja-step">
                <!-- aqui he hecho una modificacion  en los 3 pasos-->
                <a href="#step-1" type="button" class=" btn btn-primary btn-circle start-class">1</a>
                <p>Insertar jugadores</p>
              </div>
              <div class="btnCaja-step">
                <a href="#step-3" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-circle end-class" disabled="disabled">3</a>
                <p>Verificar reserva</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <div class="container">
            <form action="" role="form" method="POST">
              <div class="conf-content row" id="step-1">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                  <h3>Paso 1</h3>
                  <div class="containerP1">
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <form name="insertarJugadores" id="insertarJugadores">
                        <div class="table-responsive">
                          <table class="table" id="dynamic_field">
                            <tr>
                              <td>
                                <input type="text" name="name[] nombre" placeholder="Pulse en el + para introducir jugadores" class="form-control name_list input-group-lg" disabled />
                              </td>
                              <td><button type="button" name="add" id="add" class="btn btn-success">+</button></td>
                            </tr>
                          </table>
                        </div>
                      </form>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="conf-content row" id="step-3">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                  <h3>Paso 3</h3>
                  <div class="containerP3">
                  </div>
                  <button class="btn btn-success btn-lg pull-right" type="submit">Reservar</button>
                </div>
              </div>
              <!-- aqui termina el tercer paso -->
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer btnFooter d-flex justify-content-between">
          <button class="btn btn-primary prevBtn btn-md pull-left disabled-control" type="button" id="previous">Anterior</button>
          <button class="btn btn-success nextBtn btn-md pull-right" id="next" type="button">Siguiente</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-light btn-md close" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Estás en la versión en español de StackOverflow. Puedes: 1 - Traducir la pregunta, o 2 - postearla en la versión en inglés

Comment: como se postea a la version ingles?¿ Arriel

Comment: @Arriel hacía referencia al sitio en inglés. ¡Estás en [es.so]! Editá tu pregunta para traducirla al español, y/o formulá tu pregunta en [so]. Las preguntas que no están en el idioma del sitio terminan [cerradas](/help/closed-questions).

Comment: si lo que intentas es saber cuantos jugadores se generaron es sencillo, coloca jugador en el atributo name y al dar click en siguiente dispara un queryselectorall que te traiga todos los inputs con atributo name = a jugador

Answer (score -1):

solo coloca algo , como jugador, en el atrubuto name del input y luego en el next seleccionas todos los que tengan un atributo name = jugador, si viene en 0 sales de la funcion y sino sigues adelante

```js
var i = 1;
$('#add').click(function() {
  // condicion que puede crear hasta un maximo de 4 campos 
  if (i >= 5) return
  i++;
  var crearTablas = $(
'<tr id="row' + i + '">' +
'<td>' +
'<input type="text" name="jugador" required placeholder="Nombre Jugador" pattern="^([A-Z]{1}[a-z]+\s?)*$" class="form-control name_list"  maxlength="100"/>' +
'</td>' +
'<td>' +
'<button type="button" name="remove" id="' + i + '" class="btn btn-danger btn_remove">X</button>' +
'</td>' +
' </tr>');
  $('#dynamic_field').append(crearTablas);
});
$(document).on('click', '.btn_remove', function() {
  // guardamos el identificador del boton en la variable
  var button_id = $(this).attr("id");
  
  $('#row' + button_id + '').remove();
  // luego ponemos el contador a 1 para resetear el contador
  i = 1;
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#next').click(function() {
current_fs = $('#step-1');
let jugadores = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="jugador"]')
if(jugadores.length < 1) {
 alert("Debes ingresar al menos 1 jugador")
return
   }
else
{
 alert(`Han ingresado ${jugadores.length} jugadores`)
}
next_fs = $('#step-3');
next_fs.show();
current_fs.hide();

  });
  $('#previous').click(function() {
    current_fs = $('#step-3');
    next_fs = $('#step-1');
    next_fs.show();
    current_fs.hide();
  });
});
```

```css
#step-3{display:none;}
```

```html
<html lang="es">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<body>
  <!-- Button trigger modal -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#misModales">
    Reservar
  </button>
  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="misModales" data-bs-backdrop="static" data-bs-keyboard="false" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="abrirContenido" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <!-- aqui va el boton de cierre del modal -->
          <div class="btnCaja">
            <div class="btnCaja-fila panel-conf">
              <div class="btnCaja-step">
                <!-- aqui he hecho una modificacion  en los 3 pasos-->
                <a href="#step-1" type="button" class=" btn btn-primary btn-circle start-class">1</a>
                <p>Insertar jugadores</p>
              </div>
              <div class="btnCaja-step">
                <a href="#step-3" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-circle end-class" disabled="disabled">3</a>
                <p>Verificar reserva</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <div class="container">
            <form action="" role="form" method="POST">
              <div class="conf-content row" id="step-1">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                  <h3>Paso 1</h3>
                  <div class="containerP1">
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <form name="insertarJugadores" id="insertarJugadores">
                        <div class="table-responsive">
                          <table class="table" id="dynamic_field">
                            <tr>
                              <td>
                                <input type="text" name="name[] nombre" placeholder="Pulse en el + para introducir jugadores" class="form-control name_list input-group-lg" disabled />
                              </td>
                              <td><button type="button" name="add" id="add" class="btn btn-success">+</button></td>
                            </tr>
                          </table>
                        </div>
                      </form>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="conf-content row" id="step-3">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                  <h3>Paso 3</h3>
                  <div class="containerP3">
                  </div>
                  <button class="btn btn-success btn-lg pull-right" type="submit">Reservar</button>
                </div>
              </div>
              <!-- aqui termina el tercer paso -->
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer btnFooter d-flex justify-content-between">
          <button class="btn btn-primary prevBtn btn-md pull-left disabled-control" type="button" id="previous">Anterior</button>
          <button class="btn btn-success nextBtn btn-md pull-right" id="next" type="button">Siguiente</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-light btn-md close" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta.. pero no contestamos preguntas en otro idioma que no sea el oficial (español)...

Comment: No es la primera vez que respondés a una pregunta que termina(rá) cerrada por estar en otro idioma. ¡Aguardá a que el OP corrija su pregunta! Y no olvides responder a preguntas _bien formadas_. Referencia: [answer].